SQLite Error while migration in KMM project
I am trying to perform migration in a KMM project.
As I can see migration is being well done in database, but I am getting this error:

org.sqlite.SQLiteException: [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or
missing database (no such column: Measurement.migrationTestField)

This is my migration File.
ALTER TABLE Measurement ADD COLUMN migrationTextField TEXT DEFAULT "Migration OK" NOT NULL;

And Measurement.sq
    import kotlin.Boolean;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Measurement (
    id TEXT NOT NULL,
    date TEXT NOT NULL,
    interfaceType TEXT NOT NULL,
    operator TEXT NOT NULL,
    status INTEGER NOT NULL,
    testType INTEGER NOT NULL,
    sent INTEGER AS Boolean NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    technology INTEGER NOT NULL,
    migrationTestField TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT "Migration OK",
    PRIMARY KEY (id, date)
);

insertMeasurement:
INSERT INTO Measurement(
    id,
    date,
    interfaceType,
    operator,
    status,
    testType,
    sent,
    technology,
    migrationTestField
)
VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);

updateMeasurement:
UPDATE Measurement
SET interfaceType = ?, operator = ?, status = ?, sent = ? WHERE id = ? AND date = ?;

selectMeasurementsGroupById:
SELECT * FROM Measurement GROUP BY id;

selectInProgressMeasurements:
SELECT * FROM Measurement WHERE status = 2;

selectPendingMeasurements:
SELECT * FROM Measurement WHERE sent = 0;

This is Table before migration

After applying changes to project everything seems to be ok, running app and opening .db file again table is correctly modified.


I am getting this error in jvm side
And this is my DatabaseManager Imp
internal actual class DatabaseDriverFactory {
companion object {
    private const val DATABASE_NAME = "any.db"
    val DATABASE_RELATIVE_PATH: String by lazy {
        val userHome = System.getProperty("user.home")
        userHome + File.separator + ".whatever" + File.separator + "data"
    }
    val DATABASE_URL = "jdbc:sqlite:$DATABASE_RELATIVE_PATH/$DATABASE_NAME"
}

actual fun createDriver(): SqlDriver {
    val properties = Properties().apply { put("foreign_keys", "true") }
    val driver: SqlDriver = JdbcSqliteDriver(DATABASE_URL, properties)
    initializeOrUpdateDatabase(driver)
    return driver
}

private fun initializeOrUpdateDatabase(driver: SqlDriver) {
    if (!databaseExists()) {
        createDatabaseRelativePath()
        initSchema(driver)
    } else {
        doMigration(driver)
    }
}

private fun initSchema(driver: SqlDriver) {
    val latestVersion = AgentDatabase.Schema.version
    val currentVersion = getCurrentDatabaseVersion(driver)
    Logger.debug("$TAG Database does not exist. Creating new database schema.")
    Logger.debug("$TAG Current DB Version: $currentVersion, Latest DB Version: $latestVersion")
    AgentDatabase.Schema.create(driver)
    if (currentVersion < latestVersion) doMigration(driver)
}

private fun doMigration(driver: SqlDriver) {
    val latestVersion = AgentDatabase.Schema.version
    while (getCurrentDatabaseVersion(driver) < latestVersion) {
        Logger.debug("$TAG Updating database schema from ${getCurrentDatabaseVersion(driver)} to $latestVersion.")
        try {
            AgentDatabase.Schema.migrate(driver, getCurrentDatabaseVersion(driver), latestVersion)
            updateDatabaseVersion(driver, getCurrentDatabaseVersion(driver) +1)
        } catch (exception: Exception) {
            updateDatabaseVersion(driver, getCurrentDatabaseVersion(driver) + 1)
        }
    }
}

private fun updateDatabaseVersion(driver: SqlDriver, newVersion: Long) {
    val jdbcDriver = driver as JdbcSqliteDriver
    jdbcDriver.getConnection().createStatement().use { statement ->
        statement.execute("PRAGMA user_version = $newVersion;")
    }
}

private fun getCurrentDatabaseVersion(driver: SqlDriver): Long {
    val jdbcDriver = driver as JdbcSqliteDriver
    val connection = jdbcDriver.getConnection()
    connection.createStatement().use { statement ->
        val resultSet = statement.executeQuery("PRAGMA user_version;")
        if (resultSet.next()) {
            return resultSet.getLong(1)
        }
    }
    return 0
}

private fun createDatabaseRelativePath() {
    val path = File(DATABASE_RELATIVE_PATH)
    if (!path.exists()) {
        path.mkdirs()
    }
}

private fun databaseExists(): Boolean {
    return File("$DATABASE_RELATIVE_PATH/$DATABASE_NAME").exists()
}

Migration logs seems to be ok.
13.05.2024 10:52:51.233 [AWT-EventQueue-0] DEBUG ROOT - DatabaseManager:  Updating database schema from 2 to 3.

I have no idea what I am doing wrong, Thanks for any help.

Do you have any database validation with your schema in your code? I can see a migrationTextField in the picture but not a migrationTestField.
